# heatmap.2 node stack overflow

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to use heatmap.2 in R to draw a heatmap. like this:

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(data), col=redgreen(75), scale="row", key=T, 
           keysize=1.5,density.info="none", trace="none",cexCol=0.9, labRow=NA)
```

However, when it running, an error like this happen:

```
Error in setmid(d[[j]], type) : node stack overflow
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Running your code with `data <- matrix(rnorm(75*100), ncol=10)` seems to work fine. So there's something up with your data. We're going to need to know what your data looks like.

Comment: can you post results of `str(your_data)`

Comment: Work-around posted at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877485/554531